# What are some of the nontrivial way to define open set on natural numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We can define topology/open sets on real numbers by defining a metrics first. I'm curious of what we can do with natural numbers that is interesting/nontrivial.

Comment: The $p$-adic metric for a prime $p$ is interesting. Studied a lot in number theory and algebraic geometry.

Comment: Fix a bijection with the rational numbers, and use the natural metric to define a topology on the natural numbers.

Comment: Generalizing beyond metrics to general topologies: Although there are a number of examples which are motivated specifically by the natural numbers as per Henno's comment, note that you can equivalently ask about *countable topological spaces* in general. There are lots of interesting ones of those (for example: it turns out there are lots of countable Hausdorff connected spaces!) and if I recall correctly a number of them appear in Steen and Seebach's excellent book ["Counterexamples in Topology"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology).

Comment: It's also worth noting - although this isn't really relevant to your question per se, just something you might find interesting - that there is [lots of interesting mathematics about *finite* topological spaces](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/FINITEBOOK/FINITEBOOKCollatedDraft.pdf)!

Answer (score 0):

As Noah says in the comments, if you don't require any compatibility with the usual arithmetic operations on the natural numbers then you're just asking what the countable topological spaces spaces. Of course there are many of these, e.g. any countable subset of any other topological space you care about. It's unclear to me what can be usefully said at this level of generality.

There are some topologies on $\mathbb{N}$ that interact nicely with arithmetic. One of them is the [Furstenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes) topology, whose open sets are unions of arithmetic progressions. Furstenburg famously gave a proof using this topology that there are infinitely many primes. As Henno says in the comments, there are also the [$p$-adic topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Topology), where we only consider arithmetic progressions with common difference a power of a particular prime $p$. These are important in number theory.